# Selecting table cells based on class using jQuery

Tags: jquery, css

I have a layout similar to this:

```
<tr>
    <td class="topCategoryRow"><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="catlink">Some Category</a></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="subCategoryRow">A sub category under Some Category</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="subCategoryRow">Another sub category under Some Category</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="topCategoryRow"><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="catLink">Another Category</a></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="subCategoryRow">A sub category under Another Category</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="subCategoryRow">Another sub category under Another Category</td>
</tr>
```

What I'm trying to do is attach a click handler on `catLink` classes. I want to be able to select the `subCategoryRows` under the `topCategoryRows`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $(".catLink").click(function() {
            $(".subCategoryRow").show(); // This selector is wrong
        });
    });
 </script>
```

The code I have selects ALL `subCategoryRow`'s. I want to select only the ones under the category selected. Can someone help me build the correct selector?

Comment: Perhaps your classes would be better attached to the `<tr>`s and not the `<td>`s?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
$(function() {
    $(".catlink").click(function() {
       $(this).closest('tr').nextUntil("tr:has(.catlink)").find('.subCategoryRow').show();
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/YmrF9/)

*note: class names are case sensitive - you have used `catlink` and `catLink`*

Comment: This works, except for the last item though. Keep in mind that there will be no more "catlink" tags after the last one.

Comment: @icemanind you are using the class name as `catLink` for the second item that is the problem change it to `catlink` checkout the fiddle

Answer (score 0):

Try this too.

```
$(function() {
    $(".catLink").click(function() {
        var xCurrentObj = $(this).closest('tr');
        $('.subCategoryRow').filter(function(){
            return ($(this).parent().index() > xCurrentObj.index());
        }).show();
    });
});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/YmrF9/2/)